# Accessing DB2 through Cygwin

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin, db2

How can I access DB2 through Cygwin?

I’m working on a Windows platform but need to run some bash files and within these bash files I’ve to execute some DB2 commands to test different settings and indexes. However, I can’t seem to get it to work.

Comment: I've deleted some of the noise from your question. Reading what's left, there's really not a lot for us to go from. Like Matrix noted: please tell us *what* doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-02/msg00635.html) post on the cygwin users mailing list from back in 2003 that might work. If not, please provide some details on what exactly is not working to help pinpoint the problem for others.

Comment: Though I agree with most of the answers in [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), +1 for finding that link while there's really not much to go on.

Comment: The link is blocked in my workplace, thus this answer is bad.